# SQL, can i make a pair of indexes?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Is it possible to somehow write down the indexes with a pair, for example `cityID` and `mode`, making both unique? Not separately, but in order to prevent records of the type

```
| cityID | url         |  mode   |
   707    "_kya-krya_"    current
   707    "_kya-krya-2_"  current
```

I'm asking about the pair, because if they are unique individually, then they do not get to do this:

```
| cityID |   url        |  mode   |
 707       "_blabla_"     current
 70985267  "_blalba-2_"   current
```

Comment: Yes, you may create a unique index on a pair of columns.  But what exact behavior are you expecting in your second example?  It isn't clear what the logic is, though I doubt a unique index would do what you want.

Comment: have you tried composite key?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is:

```
create unique index unq_t_cityID_mode on t(cityID, mode);
```

You can also do this with a unique constraint, which can even be declared in the `create table` statement:

```
create table t (
    cityId . . .,
    mode . . .,
    . . .
    unique (cityId, mode)
);
```